# sql oracle find same data and take newest one

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, date

I got a SQL which gives me the following output:

```
      column1 column2 column3    column4     column5 column6 column7 column8 column9

 #1   blabla  blabla  15.10.2012 30.11.2014  7224    blabla  blabla  blabla  blabla
 #2   blabla  blabla  14.20.2011 30.11.2013  7224    blabla  blabla  blabla  blabla
```

`column3` and `column4` are DATE.

My SQL:

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5,
(SELECT ov_merkmalwertid FROM V_OV_MERKMALWERT WHERE objektfk = table2.OV_OBJEKTID AND MERKMAL = 'censored1') column6,
(SELECT ov_merkmalwertid FROM V_OV_MERKMALWERT WHERE objektfk = table2.OV_OBJEKTID AND MERKMAL = 'censored2') column7,
(SELECT ov_merkmalwertid FROM V_OV_MERKMALWERT WHERE objektfk = table2.OV_OBJEKTID AND MERKMAL = 'censored3') column8,
(SELECT ov_merkmalwertid FROM V_OV_MERKMALWERT WHERE objektfk = table2.OV_OBJEKTID AND MERKMAL = 'censored4') column9
from
table1,
table2
where
table1.DEVICEID = table2.OV_OBJEKTID;
```

As you can see the date in `#1 column4` is "newer" than `#2 column4`.

I need a SQL that gives me my output but checks if the number in `column5` are the same. If they are the same it just shows me the data which has the newest DATE in `column4`.

The final result should be not showing `#2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the record with the most recent `column4` date per `column5`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column5  ORDER BY column4 DESC) AS rn,
       column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, ... etc
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.DEVICEID = table2.OV_OBJEKTID ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

You should also be using ANSI standard `JOIN` syntax, like in the query above.

Comment: Thanks this helped me out as well!

Answer (score 1):

Select `MAX` of `column4` and group by `column5`:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, MAX(column4), column5,
       (SELECT ov_merkmalwertid 
          FROM V_OV_MERKMALWERT 
         WHERE objektfk = table2.OV_OBJEKTID 
           AND MERKMAL = 'censored1') column6,
       (SELECT ov_merkmalwertid 
          FROM V_OV_MERKMALWERT 
         WHERE objektfk = table2.OV_OBJEKTID 
           AND MERKMAL = 'censored2') column7,
       (SELECT ov_merkmalwertid 
          FROM V_OV_MERKMALWERT 
         WHERE objektfk = table2.OV_OBJEKTID  
           AND MERKMAL = 'censored3') column8,
       (SELECT ov_merkmalwertid 
          FROM V_OV_MERKMALWERT 
         WHERE objektfk = table2.OV_OBJEKTID 
           AND MERKMAL = 'censored4') column9
  FROM table1,
       table2
 WHERE table1.DEVICEID = table2.OV_OBJEKTID
 GROUP BY column5;
```

Comment: Thanks so far for your help - what do you mean with number5? Maqybe column5?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry! **p.s.**: note that `MAX` is not working, if the date in `column4` is stored as a `VARCHAR`

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: @jarlh: you are right - that would be the more precise notation. Using a small Fiddle I checked whether I could omit the columns or not - and in fact it did (also know as `GROUP BY extension` in MySQL). Usually you would group by `column1, column2, column3, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9`